# blocking threads in java using semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

My aim is to get many thread access to a static attribut "nbPlace" ONE AT THE TIME, and decrement it. I'm using a variable "mutex" to let one thread decrement everytime , however something went wrong. Here's my code:

```
public class Client extends Thread{

static int nbPlace=10;
static int mutex=1;

public Client(String name){
    super(name);
}
public void run(){
    if (mutex==1) {
        mutex=0;
        decrementer(getName());
        mutex=1;
    } else
        try {
            join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
static void decrementer(String nomThread){
     nbPlace--; System.out.println("dec par "+nomThread+" ... nbplace="+nbPlace);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Client [] t= new Client[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) t[i]=new  Client ("thread n° "+i);
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) t[i].start();

}
```

}

Comment: Why not just make your `decrementer` method `synchronized`?

Comment: "something went wrong" can you be more specific?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to be using either an AtomicInteger or a CountdownLatch? Or a Semaphore, for that matter.

Comment: I'm expecting all thread decrement "nbPlace" , but only the first one did it.

Comment: Does it help if you make it volatile? (and mutex too)

Comment: I tried synchronized and volatile , didin't work

Comment: In `run()` just have your call to `decrementer()`, and make `decrementer()` synchronized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java already has a semaphore implementation, just use it:

```
public class Client extends Thread{

    static int nbPlace=10;
    private final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    public Client(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            sem.acquire();
            decrementer(getName());
            sem.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static void decrementer(String nomThread){
         nbPlace--; System.out.println("dec par "+nomThread+" ... nbplace="+nbPlace);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Client [] t= new Client[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) t[i]=new  Client ("thread n° "+i);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) t[i].start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The call to `release()` above should be in a `finally` block or if decrementer() throws, the permit will never be released.

Comment: This will not reliably work - do not use this
Post by Vladimir Korenev is more elegant and reliable

Answer (score 1):

No, things do not work this way in Java. You cannot access mutable data concurrently without proper synchronization.

The simplest way to make this code tread safe:

```
static int nbPlace = 10;
static final Object object = new Object();

public Client(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (object) {
        decrementer(getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What Andy Turner said in the comments is correct use **countdown latch**.

I disagree with the accepted answer because if the try catch fails then the semaphore will never release. You should always release in the finally block. The most simple way to lock code is a synchronized block.

```
public synchronized void myMethod(){
    //anything here is only able to be run by one thread at a time
}
```

The other form of synchronized is

```
public class MyClass {
final Object lock = new Object();
public void myMethod(){
    synchronized(lock){
        //anything here is only able to be run by one thread at a time
    }
}
```

you can also use a reentrant lock

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class MyClass{
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public void myMethod(){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            //anything here is only able to be run by one thread at a time
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is the ReadWriteLock which allows unlimited threads to read as long as a thread doesn't have the write lock

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class MyClass {
    final ReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    public void myReadMethod(){
        Lock lock = rwlock.readLock();
        lock.lock();
        try{
            //anything here is only able to be run
            //by any thread that is reading as long
            //as another thread doesn't have the write lock
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void myWriteMethod(){
        Lock lock = rwlock.writeLock();
        lock.lock();
        try{
            //anything here is only able to be run by one thread at a time
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

I've never used Semaphores, so I can't speak on them.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread hits the `if (mutex==1) {` condition when another thread is in that block, it jumps to the `else` and calls `join()`.

Calling `join()` on the current Thread (not on another Thread) means that the current Thread is waiting for itself to die, which can't happen, so these threads block forever.